# customize tableViewCell heights

Tags: swift, uitableview, xcode7

So I am trying to set 3 different tableView cells in a UITableView with different heights for each cell. I am wondering how do I return the 3 different cells each with their own custom heights?

Thanks for the pointers or help!

```
// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

    return 3
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if(section == 0) {
        return 1
    }
    if(section == 1) {
        return 1
    }
    else {
        return 10
    }

}


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    switch indexPath.section{
    case 0:
        let myProfile = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("ProfileHeaderCell") as! VideoTableViewCell



        return myProfile

    case 1:
        let myInfo = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("AlbumCell") as! AlbumTableViewCell


        return myInfo

      default:
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("TravelBookCell") as! TravelBookTableViewCell


        return cell

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {

    let section = indexPath.section
    if(section == 0) {
      return 20
    }
    if(section == 1) {
      return 30
    }
    else {
      return 50
    }

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can switch the frame's size of the cell. Here is an example on the case 0 of the switch.

```
    case 0:
            let myProfile = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("ProfileHeaderCell") as! VideoTableViewCell

myProfile.frame.size = CGSize(width: /*CGFloat*/, height: /*CGFloat*/)  

            return myProfile
```

Comment: it is not changing the height...?     
       
            myProfile.frame.size = CGSize(width: 600.0, height: 60.0)

            return myProfile

Comment: That's weird have you switched the rowHeight anywhere? If you want you can also do this in the storyboard by making the cell bigger? Double check by putting a big height like 350.

Comment: as of right now all the cell heights for all 3 sections are coming in at the storyboard table view row height settings...so I would imagine I need to override that or somehow set that tableview row height value to empty...?